# use_outer_join option (true) in hibernate config file doesn't generate outer joins 

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate

I have use_outer_join option set to true in a configuration file.

I have also a mapped db table. I saw in sql logs that for a foreign key, hibernate is generating separate select for each records. It is not using the join to obtain data from primary table.

Is there something I forgot about?
What else can be wrong with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is like that: Specifying the outer join in the mapping file is not sufficient.

If you want to force an outer join, then you have to specify it in the HQL statement. For example

```
from firstTable as a outer join fetch a.secondTable as b where ...
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me. (I had to remove "outer" from that hsql). I am just wondering why @Ram Reddy solution didn't work. Do I always have to explicitly join table in order to force hibernate to use joins with foreign tables?

Comment: Yes, you have to. When you specify the join in the mapping file only, then hibernate interprets this as 'should be like a join' and executes two different select statements which have the same effect as the joined statement. I don't know why, but I guess it is due to the lazy loading philosophy: If the joined data is not used, they don't need to be loaded, but in an explicit join they are always loaded. If you are sure the joined data will be used, then an explicit join in the HQL statement is faster, especially if the database is on a different computer than the application.

Answer (score 0):

Check your relationship mapping. If nothing is specified by default proxy will be returned for the child ..and the child will be loaded when you access any propery of it. It will be loaded in a seperate SQL select.

You should use "outer-join=true" in the collection mapping. (if hibernate.use_outer_join is true in the configuration and collection mapping has outer-join="true"...then only hibernate will generate outer joins).

Comment: I have set in a collection mapping for a many-to-one property, attribute outer-join for true, I had also attribute: fetch="join" and also in a configuration file use_outer_join set to true and still hibernate was making selects for every row in a source table. (The hsql is just: "from table")...